# How to change style property in react hooks on function call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

On function call i was changing the image style using useState hooks
I was sending these property as an props
basically i want to a function which should contain style property  for img and pass it to another component as props`style = {{opacity: ".3"}}`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import BackgroundImage from '../Image/Homepage/background.png'
const HomePage = () => {
const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);
const [image, setImage] = useState(BackgroundImage)

return (
        <div>
       <img src={image} className="first-image" alt="backGroundImage" />
        </div>
                <Modals
                    show={modalShow}
                    onhide={() => setModalShow(false)}
                    sendImages = {() => setImage( style = {{opacity: ".3"}} )}

                />
)}
```

this is throwing an error
`sendImages = {() => setImage( style = {{opacity: ".3"}} )}`
I think this not right approach

Comment: Any code of `BackgroundImage`?

Comment: i am importing the image

Comment: what is the detailed error?

Comment: basically i want to a function which should contain style property  for img and pass it to another component as props```style = {{opacity: ".3"}}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to make `opacity` dynamic, instead you manipulate image src...

---

```
     import React, { useState } from 'react';
     import BackgroundImage from '../Image/Homepage/background.png'

     const HomePage = () => {
       const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);
       const [image, setImage] = useState(BackgroundImage);
       const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(1);

       return (
         <>
          <div>
            <img src={image} className="first-image" style={{opacity}} alt="backGroundImage" />
          </div>
          <Modals
            show={modalShow}
            onhide={() => setModalShow(false)}
            sendImages = {() => setOpacity(0.3)}
          />
         </>
         )}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only wish to update the style property on function call, you must store the style property in state and not the image. Also the syntax for setImage is incorrect in your code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import BackgroundImage from '../Image/Homepage/background.png'
const HomePage = () => {
const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);
const [imageStyle, setImageStyle] = useState({})

return (
    <>
      <div>
         <img src={BackgroundImage} style={imageStyle} className="first-image" alt="backGroundImage" />
      </div>
      <Modals
          show={modalShow}
          onhide={() => setModalShow(false)}
          sendImages = {() => setImageStyle({opacity: ".3"})}

      />
    </>
)}
```

**NOTE**: Also please note that state updaters with hooks do not merge the values but override it. So if you wish to update only certain properties make use of state updater callback method to return the merged values yourself